tailwind css/ images not loading on vercel deployed website
following is my next-js website, when i run it locally it runs fine, but when i deploy it on vercel, the images and the css does not load, tried all solutions on the internet, but nothing works
This is the vercel url:    https://madhura-borkar.vercel.app/
This is the git repo:    https://github.com/madhura824/madhura-borkar

It does not seem like that from here. You probably want to try again

Empty Cache and hard reload
Reset/try some other internet connection
Try some other browser or device

Image of website

yes its now working fine. I added the vercel.json file with the routes property
"routes": [
{
"src": "/(.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|webp|svg|gif|ico|css|js|map|woff|woff2|ttf|otf|eot|pdf))$",
"dest": "/public/$1"
}    ]
This redirected all the static assets related requests to the public folder, and it worked for me
